# Convert number to Decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have a number like this 20000 and a other number like this 3.
the second number is the decimal place of first number. the result must 
show like this 20.000 but i have no idea how i can do it.

I have tried it with this function:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3LtM/

```
function getNumber(number, decimal) { 

    var n=number.toFixed(decimal); 
    return n;
}

getNumber(20000, 3)
```

but the result are are "20000.000".

do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide your number first by your decimal to the power of 10 value and then use `toFixed()`

```
function getNumber(number, decimal) {
   var n = (number/Math.pow(10,decimal)).toFixed(decimal); 
   return n;
}
```

Then your call `getNumber(20000, 3);` will return the right formating 20.000.

Here is your updatet fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3LtM/17/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getNumber(number, decimal) {
    var n = number;
    for (i = 0; i < decimal; i++) {
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return parseFloat(n).toFixed(decimal);
}

alert(getNumber(20000, 3));
```

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3LtM/9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumber(number, decimal) {
    return (number / Math.pow(10,decimal)).toFixed(decimal);
}

alert(getNumber(20000, 3));
```

alerts "20.000" :)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3LtM/12/)